# Having mac start issues after upgrading to 22.04, wifi can't see networks

Tags: wireless, laptop, hp, iwlwifi, 22.04

After I updated to 22.04, my computer displayed the following error on startup:

```
[    0.152522] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[    0.152522] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[   59.858307] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 0
[   59.954767] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 1
[   60.050188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 2
[   60.050188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 0
[   60.050188] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 1
[   61.011865] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 2
[   61.107249] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 0
[   61.205198] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 1
[   61.302094] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 mas start retry 2
```

When the computer fully boots up, it can't seem to find any wifi networks. Currently I have to use an ethernet USB tether to my phone.

Output of lsusb && lspci && rfkill list all && mokutil --sb-state

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b5d5 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0aa7 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 3168 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 038: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak] (rev 10)
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode
```

Output of sudo lshw -C network

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 15
       serial: b4:b6:86:4d:b6:03
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 60:f6:77:6a:a4:dc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic firmware=29.0bd893f3.0 3168-29.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes
       resources: irq:129 memory:b1000000-b1001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: a
       bus info: usb@1:3
       logical name: usb0
       serial: de:1c:45:6e:9a:f7
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=5.15.0-27-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.166 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297433/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios

Comment: Same issue here, have you found anything? For me with an AX210 coming from a woring AX200 setup

Comment: @nico Did you try the BIOS change suggested in my link? Did it make any improvement?

Comment: @chili555 Sadly no, it did fix the VMX and SGX warnings but not the iwlwifi warnings or my issues with my wifi.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolve it by uninstalling `backport-iwlwifi-dkms`

```shell
sudo apt remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Got the idea from [this thread](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=379040).