# Why is Ubuntu failing to boot?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, fsck

**UPDATE #2:**

Please read the below sections first.

The version of Ubuntu on the computer is 22.04.2 LTS. I believe the OS is installed on an internal SSD but am not 100% certain, this computer is one of several in a lab I work in, so I did not make the computer myself. I do know the computer was assembled by someone in the lab, and they handled the construction of the computer and the installation of the OS themselves.

After disconnecting all peripherals, I only receive the following messages:

```
[0.155173] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabeld by BIOS
[0.155176] x86/cpu: SGX disabed by BIOS.
/dev/sdb2: clean, 2002793/6102208 files, 232117602/244059136 blocks
[3.556883]
```

**UPDATE #1:**

My original post is below. There were two external hard drives connected to the computer, which I have now removed, and the amount of error messages has gone down significantly. I am going to continue to work in my own time to try and resolve this issue, but any additional help would be greatly appreciated:

Here are the new messages I now receive when trying to boot:

```
[0.154795] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[0.154799] x86/cpu: SGX diabled by BIOS.
[2.851156] usbhid 1-3:1.3: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[3.032315] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0005.0005: No inputs registered, leaving
/dev/sdb2: clean, 2002793/61022208 files, 232115550/244059136 blocks
[4.469430]
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**

I have an Ubuntu system that was previously running just fine. After a shutdown one day, it no longer will boot completely. When I turn on the computer I am met with the following messages:

```
[0.154791] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[0.154795] x86/cpu: SGX diabled by BIOS.
[3.027456] scsi 6:0:0:1: Wrong diagnostic page: asked for 1 got 8
[3.027611] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[3.027757] scsi 6:0:0:1: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[3.087716] usbhid 1-3:1.3: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[3.272330] hid-generic 0003:0D8C:0005.0005: No inputs registered, leaving
/dev/sdb2: clean, 2002797/61022208 files, 231852122/244059136 blocks
[5.297522]
```

If anyone could help me out I would greatly appreciate it! I can try an provide any additional information that may be useful to solving the issue

Comment: Hi Tommy! The errors point to some kind of issue with hard drives or external usb drives... Please disconnect every USB device and retry. Also let us know what version of Ubuntu you're using and how/where you installed it to. (Probably on an internal SSD, right?)

Comment: I should note (and will probably add this to my post) that this system was not made by myself. It is one of several computers in a lab I work in. I am pretty sure that Ubuntu is installed on an internal SSD (not HDD). The computer is running Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS. I will also update my original post with the messages I saw after disconnecting all peripherals (besides the monitor of course lol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, none of these errors should prevent your system from booting...

- Find info on the VMX message [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1300834/21008)
- Find info on the SGX message [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418997/21008)
- The two lines about usbhid are probably there because there's an issue with a remaining USB peripheral. (Keyboard? Mouse?)

If Ubuntu really doesn't boot (sometimes it takes quite some time to progress from this screen, so make sure to let it sit a while), try switching back to an older kernel. You can select an older kernel from the grub menu on boot. Let us know, if you need help with that.

**Update:** The file system was full. Deleting some files from recovery mode fixed it. Good job, Tommy. :)

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, how long is "a while"? A few minutes? A couples hours? Just curious how long I should wait for.

I am also relatively new to Ubuntu, so the grub menu is something that I didn't even know about until you just mentioned. I will look at that maybe.

Comment: No worries. :) If you're running off a big and old hard drive you'd maybe need to wait a minute or two at that screen - not longer.
Exactly, selecting an older kernel and/or recovery mode from the grub menu would be your next steps now.

Comment: Aha, so by using the grub menu I was able to look at a system summary... you'll never guess what the issue was. The main drive was 100% full *facepalm*. Anyhow, using terminal I was able to delete some folders of data that I know I have backed up, and now the system boots. I was messing around with TensorFlow and a bunch of stuff so I probably just ended up generating a bunch of stuff and filled the drive on accident. Now it's my problem to free up space on the system. Anyhow, thank you for all of the help!

Comment: Ha, so that's what it was. Glad you found the reason it hung! Could you mark the question as answered?

Comment: I think I did it just now. First time using this website so I'm just a *little* lost lol

Comment: Haha, no worries. Yup, you marked the question as resolved, thanks! :)