Hard restart recovery error
Good day!
I am new to Linux in general. I've been trying to fix this issue for some time now reading other posts but I've had no luck. Here is what shows up on screen:
Picture of issue
Since the picture doesn't seem to work:
[  0.144972] x86/CPU VMX (Outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
/dev/sdb2: recovering journal
/dev/sdb2: Superblock needs_recovery flag is clear, but journal has data
/dev/sdb2: Run journal anyways
/dev/sdb2: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
(i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4
The root filesystem on /dev/sdb2 requires a manual fsck
BusyBox v1.30.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.30.1-7ubuntu3) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.
(initramfs)
I have tried solutions posted on similar issues but none have worked. Maybe my case is a little different. Any suggestions on what I should do?
I have tried  fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY and the result is:
fsck.ext4 unable to set Superblock flags on /dev/sdb2 (Nextline) /dev/sdb2: 
********* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********


Hi can you describe your issue, the link that you posted shows: oh no, that request didn't look right
RayID: 887d429388e40a27

@amar, I think I've fixed it. I'm on mobile so I'll just add the issue to the original post.

@amar it is now included in text form. It was tough to type out haha

The first part means that your bios virtualization technology is disabled see here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297433/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios

Does this answer your question? fsck error on boot: /dev/sda6: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Ok, I have fixed that and that line no longer appears but the rest still does

@karel it does not unfortunately. I have tried that and the result is: fsck.ext4 unable to set Superblock flags on /dev/sdb2 (Nextline) /dev/sdb2: ********* WARNING: Filesystem still has errors **********

If the fsck didn't work see here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/327863/112217

@OrganicMarble so it seems that the SSD is no longer with us ☹️. I had the suspicion having done some digging but I was hoping, me being a noob, I was missing something. I will take it to a recovery service to see if I can get my files at least. Thank you for your help!
