Im stuck in the x86/cpu: VMX outside txt disabled by bios screen
I have been starting up my Ubuntu pc but get met with this messages that keeps me from logging into my pc

Have you tried searching at all? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297433/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios and https://bobcares.com/blog/vmx-outside-txt-disabled-by-bios/

This question is similar to: VMX (outside TXT) : disabled by bios. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I don’t have windows so the suggestions don’t really help me
